# Make install fails, make returns nothing to be done for 'all-am'

Tags: makefile

I am installing a C++ library called Rheolef on my Ubuntu 14 which is installed on a Virtual Machine. The host OS is Win7. 
According to the installation procedure, I should use "make" and then "make install". 
After make, I get something like:

```
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `make-included'.
grep '^dnl[     ][      ]*#' ../../configure.ac | \
      sed -e 's/^dnl[     ][      ]*//' -e 's/^#//'  | \
      sed -e "s/\@PACKAGE\@/rheolef/g" -e "s/\@VERSION\@/6.6/g" | \
      ../../config/col -b -x | ../../config/doc2texi -chapter -file configure.ac > INSTALL.texi
cp ../../INSTALL INSTALL.txt
Making all in pexamples
make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in pusrman
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doxygen
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
```

I initially thought this is not an error as it has also been indicated so in some other forums, but when I try make install, then I get an error which is very long, but has something like:

```
​make  install-data-hook
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-hook'.
Making install in pexamples
make  install-am
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
```

Let me know if you need some other information. I attached the complete log file after make install.

[Log File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmgv2k8h0ufj3vo/342.docx?dl=0)

Comment: so to clarify I get 0 for `make` and 2 for `make install`

Comment: Please add a link to the build instructions you're following.

Comment: I have similar problem where I wrote my own automake and autoconf files.  When run the make command, I got nothing. No work is done and the target all-am seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be that all the associated files have been generated right(the shared and the archived libraries). So basically there is nothing to do. You could try running 
**make clean** 
and then run
**make**